# Setting up LDAP authentication in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, active-directory, ldap

I want to use LDAP authentication in my application. The examples I have come across use a simple AD structure. The company AD I want to authenticate against uses the structure below:

[image]

The "OU=Users" is where the users exist and I want to search against. This as seen is present at multiple places in nested OUs. I did try setting up authentication, but it keeps failing saying Bad credentials even though they are right. Is this due to the structure we have ?

The configuration looks like this:

```
    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
        GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource().url("ldap://url/DC=example,DC=com")
                .managerDn("sampleaccount,OU=ServiceAccounts,DC=example,DC=com").managerPassword("password")
                .and().userSearchBase("DC=example,DC=com").userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})");
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to go about this ?

EDIT:
The logs show this:

```
2016-06-14 15:00:26.948 DEBUG 13792 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
2016-06-14 15:00:26.948 DEBUG 13792 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.l.a.LdapAuthenticationProvider     : Processing authentication request for user: testUser
2016-06-14 15:00:26.948 DEBUG 13792 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.l.s.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch      : Searching for user 'testUser', with user search [ searchFilter: '(sAMAccountName={0})', searchBase: 'OU=OU1,OU=OU2,OU=OU3,OU=OU4,DC=example,DC=com', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
2016-06-14 15:00:27.742 DEBUG 13792 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
2016-06-14 15:00:27.742 DEBUG 13792 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'DC=example,DC=com'
 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'DC=example,DC=com'
 ]; remaining name 'ou=Users,ou=OU2,ou=OU3,ou=OU4,dc=example,dc=com'
2016-06-14 15:00:27.742 DEBUG 13792 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2016-06-14 15:00:27.742 DEBUG 13792 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint@2bb83072
2016-06-14 15:00:27.742 DEBUG 13792 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@7a9711fa
2016-06-14 15:00:27.742 DEBUG 13792 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-06-14 15:00:27.742 DEBUG 13792 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you'd share how you did setup Security.

Comment: @daniel.eichten, Edited the question.

Comment: I had a similar issue with distributed AD forests. If you don't see anything in the logs of your app I'd start by limiting the search base to one location and check if this is working. If not you have an issue in your setup, if yes it is something in the query (on the server).

Comment: @daniel.eichten, Added the log to the question. Also, I used a specific location in the search base, still did not work.

Comment: By the log I'd say the object you are looking for does not exists. Which means your search base (`OU=OU1,OU=OU2,OU=OU3,OU=OU4,DC=example,DC=com`) does not exists or your bind user does not have access to it.

Comment: I have maybe the same issue (error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238). According to [social.technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a5b0d3c1-eea8-4b8b-aaeb-c4459a926c39/0000208dnameerr-dsid03100238?forum=winserverDS) It could be an issue with the replication. Could you solve it? And yes: The element exists and I have the needed rights to look at it. First call and future calls are successfully.