# LDAP authentication in Spring without XML

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap

I'm trying to implement a login system in my application, using company's Active Directory, structure of which is similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782168/setting-up-ldap-authentication-in-spring-security) but even more branched out.
I set it up like this

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.LdapShaPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                    .userDnPatterns("uid={0}")
                    .contextSource()
                        .url("ldap://10.23.1.1:389/dc=dev,dc=company,dc=corp")
                        .and()
                    .passwordCompare()
                        .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                        .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }
}
```

When I run the application and try to log in, I get:

```
Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

Reason: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C09079A, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v23f0]; remaining name 'uid=my.name@company.hr'
```

I tried to do some research on binding, but all examples I find either use XMLs, or demonstrate a connection to the embedded ldif, neither of which is applicable here.

Comment: Are you passing the user id and domain name?

Comment: Yes, the entry is of this format `my.name@company.hr`

Comment: Take a look at [ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider](http://tcl-digitrade.com/2017/01/12/spring-boot-active-directory-authentication/).

Comment: Your bind dn seems to be wrong, ensure `userDnPatterns("uid={0}")` set a valid user dn to the AuthenticationManagerBuilder. `{0}` is a placeholder for _uid_, afaik patterns should be relative to the base dn so maybe you need to specify a user base for the auth manager to be able to build the full _dn_, for example : `userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")`